# ECMAScript 6 breaking page

Tags: ecmascript-6

Using the latest version of Chrome and Opera, I noticed that my script didn't work on localhost while using ECMAScript 6. I searched the web and found that I could enable experimental JavaScript features, yet it didn't help in fixing my issue. I switched the type back to regular ECMAScript and found out that it worked again, which left me bewildered. It says that Chrome 62 *should* support ECMAScript 6, so why doesn't it work?

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Framework</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html, body {
            background-color: #000;
            overflow: hidden;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="screen">
    If you can see this message, that means that your browser does not support HTML5.
    Please update your browser immediately in order to view this page.
</canvas>

<script src="main.js" type="text/ecmascript-6"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
alert("test");
let canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;
canvas.style.width = canvas.width + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height + "px";

let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Framework</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        html, body {
            background-color: #000;
            overflow: hidden;
            height:100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="screen">
    If you can see this message, that means that your browser does not support HTML5.
    Please update your browser immediately in order to view this page.
</canvas>

<script src="main.js" type="text/ecmascript-6"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, running it through here causes it to work, but my theory is that it's ignoring the type and running it as pure JavaScript, although I'm not 100% certain.

Comment: Why `type="text/ecmascript-6"`? This doesn’t work. Just remove it.

Comment: Is specifying the type not necessary? Do most browsers detect the script type? Because yes, removing it does work, but I'm trying to externally import objects from another file, which is why I need ECMAScript 6.

Comment: The `type` is optional. For modules use `type="module"`.